# Background running job in CakePhp 2.0

Tags: cakephp-2.0, jobs, job-scheduling

I am using cakePHP 2.0 and I need a plugin for creating a background job. I came across CakeResque but requirement for that is cakePHP 2.1+ .Please suggest me the plugins that can help in this regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the following tutorials

[Background jobs with php and resque: part 6, integration into CakePHP](http://kamisama.me/2012/10/16/background-jobs-with-php-and-resque-part-6-integration-into-cakephp/)